# Wi-Fi doesn't work with Bluetooth on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Good day! I have a Dell Inspiron 3542 laptop (Pentium 3558U, 4 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD, Intel HD Graphics, Bluetooth 4.0) and Linux Ubuntu 15.04 x64 (stable) freshly installed and updated. My main issue is that my separate Logitech Z600 Bluetooth Speakers, which I use because my laptop's built-in ones are awful, cause the Wi-Fi to stop every time I play audio (in YouTube f.e.). The Internet comes back again a bit after the speakers have stopped playing. I've had similar issues with them on Mint and other versions of Ubuntu in the past with no permanent fix, except for the command below on Mint which only prolonged the time Wi-Fi worked with Bluetooth from 5 seconds to a minute.

> echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf

However, I haven't had any problems what so ever using my built-in Bluetooth adapter with Wi-Fi and the Logitech Z600 Speakers on Windows. I've been advised to use a USB Bluetooth adapter instead of the one built-in my laptop for Linux and it just so happened that my Logitech Z600 Bluetooth Speakers came with one such Logitech Bluetooth dongle. I installed Ubuntu 15.04 a few minutes ago with it plugged in the whole time, but I still think it's not being recognized since I'm having the exact same problems I used to have with my laptop's built-in Bluetooth adapter which I believe a person told me was on one chip with the Wi-Fi. In addition, my laptop came with Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS factory pre-installed, but obviously I've changed that a billion times already. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Edit:

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` gives

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0651]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

and `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 064e:c233 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0a29 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `dmesg | grep Blue`

```
[    8.357941] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    8.357962] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.357967] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.357969] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.357976] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.545766] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.545770] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.545776] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.552489] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.552497] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.552502] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 3418.641655] usb 1-1: Product: Logitech Bluetooth Speaker Z600
[ 3418.736714] input: Logitech Logitech Bluetooth Speaker Z600 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:046D:0A29.0002/input/input11
[ 3418.790158] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A29.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech Logitech Bluetooth Speaker Z600] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done!

Comment: Why not keep using your built-in bluetooth. It is better, because coexist will work, and the chip is supported. But I will look at the dongle too.

Comment: @Pilot6 Both my built-in Bluetooth and the dongle do not work!

Comment: And if you don't plug in the dongle, internal stil does not work at all?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, which leads me to believe the dongle isn't even being recognized and it's using the built-in Bluetooth, but again I am no expert to be certain of that.

Comment: @Pilot6 Just for clarification, Internet does work while the Logitech Z600 Bluetooth Speakers are connected only if not playing audio (using the speakers). Exactly a few seconds after I play audio, it stops. It usually comes back half a minute after the audio has stopped playing and if I play audio again, the Internet stops again obviously.

Comment: Please do not use dongle for a while and add output of "dmesg | grep Blue".

Comment: Please state if your internal bluetooth works or not? It does not work at all or work with network problems? I can't get it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I posted the result of "dmesg | grep Blue" in the question now. I have Internet if the Bluetooth speakers are connected only if I don't listen to audio. When I play audio, the Internet stops and returns after a given period of time of no audio being played has passed. So, the moment I connect the BT speakers to my laptop, nothing really stops the Internet, unless I play audio from the speakers - then the Internet stops.

Comment: It looks like you gave that output with plugged dongle.

Comment: @Pilot6 I gave it with the dongle being unplugged as you told me!

Comment: @Pilot6 You didn't tell me to restart or not after unplugging the dongle. May this have caused such results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the problem. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Your built-in bluetooth Atheros adapter works, but when you use headphones, wireless disconnects.
Logitech usb dongle does not work at all.

If that is correct, then there is a solution. Logitech dongle is supported by kernel, but it conflicts with internal bt chip. You can disable internal bluetooth by

```
echo '"SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0cf3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0036", ATTR{authorized}="0"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules
```

And reboot.

Comment: Just try this first.

Comment: Stop there is an error in my command. Extra quotes are needed.

Comment: But.. it fixed my problem..

Comment: In the case my problem's fixed which I thank you immensely for, should I run the command with the quotes again or not?

Comment: Good, but to check it post "cat /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules" to your question, then we will remove it.

Comment: Do not run it again.

Comment: cat: /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules: No such file or directory

Comment: Mystery. Then we did not do anything. Is that without dongle or with?

Comment: with... After entering the command it showed ">" and I wrote "reboot", then hit enter and it showed another ">" then I typed "exit" and hit enter, when it gave me ">" again I just quit out of the Terminal.. Idk if that messed up something or did nothing..

Comment: That did nothing.

Comment: ..well, it works now, but if I reinstall for example.. any idea how to get it fixed again?

Comment: Then ask another question )) This was mysterious.